# NodeJS returns Unhandled promise rejection error

Tags: node.js, discord

My current code is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

function getData(location1) {
  var getResult = "";
  request.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/... '  + location1, (err, response) => {
  ...

  return getResult;
}

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'ping') {
      message.channel.send('pong');
    }
    else if (message.content === 'query Melbourne') {
      message.channel.send( getData('Melbourne') ) ;
    }
} );
```

The first `message.channel.send('pong')` works fine. But the second message.channel.send keeps returning the result:

```
(node:16047) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
(node:16047) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Just a novice at node so any guidance would be appreciated.

---- updated code below still errors in the same way:

```
  var PTest = function () {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          message.channel.send( getData('Melbourne') ) ;
      });
  }
  var myfunc = PTest();
  myfunc.then(function () {
       console.log("Promise Resolved");
  }).catch(function () {
       console.log("Promise Rejected");
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just send an empty message just like the warning message writes `(node:16047) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

Function `getData('Melbourne')` in `message.channel.send( getData('Melbourne') ) ;` returns empty message and the Promise is rejected. Because you didn't handle Promise rejection, node.js writes warning on the console to inform you about this situation to prevent some potential abnormal situations which can happen thru ignoring handle Promise rejection.

To handle promise rejection please call `.catch` method for this `send` function

In your updated code, you create your own *Promise*

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      message.channel.send( getData('Melbourne') ) ;
  });
```

where Promise returned by `message.channel.send` method is still unhandled. you should write `message.channel.send().catch(err => console.log(err));`

Comment: I tried to change the code after a pattern I found with .catch method. This didn't seem to fix the problem. Please see updated code above

Comment: And i actually did try to log the result value. it is not empty. So I believe I am not sending an empty message

Comment: Assumption about empty message is just based on the warning text `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

Comment: So I found it looks like the message is empty, because it seems the .send() is getting called before the getData() is finished. If I use console.log on getData() it does not return empty. So do I need to somehow make getData() synchronous?

Comment: If `getData` returns Promise then you can write `getData().then(msg => message.channel.send(msg)).catch(err=>console.log(err))`

Comment: It turns out what I really needed to fix was the async nature of the function calls. The getData() in the message.channel.send() is returning results only after message.channel.send() has already executed.